# In go, What is json.Unmarshall Maximum Depth?

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to parse JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": 185985174761277,
            "time": 1462333588680,
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "sender": {
                        "id": 1053704801343033
                    },
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": 185985174761277
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1462333588645,
                    "message": {
                        "mid": "mid.1462333588639:d44f4374dfc510c351",
                        "seq": 1948,
                        "text": "Hello World!"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using `json.Unmarshal` and passing the following struct as the interface:

```
type Message struct {
    Object string
    Entry  []struct {
        Id        int64
        Time      int64
        Messaging []struct {
            Sender struct {
                Id string
            }
            Recipient struct {
                Id string
            }
            Timestamp int64
            Message   struct {
                Mid  string
                Seq  string
                Text string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, `json.Unmarshal` does not match the JSON Response to any of the structs in `Messaging`

This function reproduces the issue exactly:

```
type Message struct {
    Object string
    Entry  []struct {
        Id        int64
        Time      int64
        Messaging []struct {
            Sender struct {
                Id string
            }
            Recipient struct {
                Id string
            }
            Timestamp int64
            Message   struct {
                Mid  string
                Seq  string
                Text string
            }
        }
    }
}
func testStruct() {
    jsonResponse := []byte(`{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": 185985174761277,
            "time": 1462333588680,
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "sender": {
                        "id": 1053704801343033
                    },
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": 185985174761277
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1462333588645,
                    "message": {
                        "mid": "mid.1462333588639:d44f4374dfc510c351",
                        "seq": 1948,
                        "text": "oijsdfoijsdfoij"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`)
    var m Message
    json.Unmarshal(jsonResponse, &m)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonResponse))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)
}
```

This is the output:

```
{Object:page Entry:[{Id:185985174761277 Time:1462333588680 Messaging:[{Sender:{Id:} Recipient:{Id:} Timestamp:0 Message:{Mid: Seq: Text:}}]}]}
```

and as you can see, all the fields inside the Message struct are not set.

My question is, is there a maximum depth that json.Unmarshal can match? and if there is not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a maximum depth on json.Unmarshal.

In your code, `Seq` field in `Message` field is defined as string, so are `Id` fields in `Sender` and `Recipient`, while in json they are integers. That should be the culprit for the missing fields.

Comment: Int64 as they are pretty big :)

Comment: this was the exact issue. I didn't realize I had strings instead of int64 in those fields! Thanks.